# Close accordion component on second click Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an Angular accordion component that opens on click (there are 3 accordions total, with only one "selected" accordion opening at time). I would like to be able to close the currently open accordion on second click. Right now I am only able to open one a time.

accordion-group.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accordion-group',
  templateUrl: './accordion-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accordion-group.component.css']
})
export class AccordionGroupComponent  {

  items = ['accordion1', 'accordion2', 'accordion3']
  selectedIndex;

  select(i){
    this.selectedIndex = i;
  }

}
```

accordion-group.component.html

```
<app-accordion
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
(click)="select(i)"
[selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
[index]="i"
[item]="item">
</app-accordion>
```

accordion.component.html

```
<div
class="accordion"
[ngClass]="currentClass">
</div>
```

accordion.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-accordion",
  templateUrl: "./accordion.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./accordion.component.css"]
})
export class AccordionComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() item;
  @Input() selectedIndex;
  @Input() index;
  currentClass;
  isOpen = false;

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.handleExpansion()
  }

  handleExpansion() {
    this.isOpen = true;
    if (this.isOpen && this.selectedIndex === this.index) this.currentClass = "expand";
    else this.currentClass = "collapse"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing i want to point out from the docs is this

```
Angular calls its ngOnChanges() method whenever it detects changes to input 
properties of the component (or directive).
```

So now when you click on the same accordion component second time its input properties are not changing at all. so you need to add the `handleExpansion` on click as well.

Also i have updated the handleExpansion logic as well

```
  handleExpansion() {
  // check if the component is selected or not
  if (this.selectedIndex === this.index) {
  // check if the component was open or not after seletion
  // if it was open collapse it and return
   if (this.isOpen) {
     this.currentClass = "collapse";
     this.isOpen = false;
     return
   }
  // if the component is selected for first time expand it
   this.currentClass = "expand";
   this.isOpen = true;
  }
  else {
  // if the component is not selected collapase it and 
   this.currentClass = "collapse";
  // close it in case if it was open earlier
   this.isOpen = false;
  }
 }
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-tpzhrd?file=app/accordion.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use model statement, just change yours array of accordions to object like this:

```
interface Accordion {
    id: number,
    index: number,
    show: boolean
}
```

Then us this like:

```
let accordions: Accordion[] = [];
accordions.push({'id': 1, 'index': 0, 'show': false});
accordions.push({'id': 2, 'index': 1, 'show': false});
accordions.push({'id': 3, 'index': 2, 'show': false});
```

Then change property `show` to show/hide clicked accordion.

Get selected accordion with `show` as true and set it to `false`:

```
let index_opened = accordions.findIndex(a => a.show);
accordions[index_opened].show = false;
```